# xquery attribute equals to id with spaces

Tags: xquery

SalesOrder Attribute is '`12345678`' (no spaces), but "`id3`" has spaces. How can I make my XQuery work to select the SalesOrder, ignoring differences in spaces?

```
"id3": "       12345678"
```

xquery

```
/SalesOrder[@SalesOrder = "{id3}"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that `$id3` with spaces removed will match `@SalesOrder`? You can remove spaces from a string using a regex and `fn:replace()`:

```
 /SalesOrder[@SalesOrder = fn:replace($id3, '\s', '')]
```

Comment: wst, appreciate your response.  Yes, if $id3  with spaces remove will match @SalesOrder.  I tried the above and it's still not liking it.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @TeamGundam Sorry, I didn't remove the quotes and brackets. Answer is corrected.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just leading and trailing whitespace that you want to normalize for, you could use the [`fn:normalize-space()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-normalize-space) function.

```
/SalesOrder[@SalesOrder = fn:normalize-space($id3)]
```

`normalize-space()` will collapse repeated spaces and eliminate spaces that are at the beginning and end of the value, but would collapse and preserve a space that was in the middle of the value

For example, `fn:normalize-space(" 123  456 789  ")` would produce "`123 456 789`".

If you want to remove all spaces, then you can use the [`fn:translate()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-translate) function.

For example, `fn:translate("  123 456  789  ", " ", "")` would produce "`123456789`") It may be slightly faster and more performant than a regex implementation such as `fn:replace()`.

Comment: I've tried all the above and it doesn't seem to be working.  I even tried just to translate the value of $id3.

/SalesOrder[@SalesOrder = fn:translate("       12345678")] 

It only works when modifying the attribute by adding the spaces to match the value in $id3, but want to get around this.  Appreciate all the responses.